# Mangopay: not possible to a card

Tags: react-native, payment, mangopay

I'm trying to add Mangopay to my react-native app.

When I try to add by `HTTPie` a card, I get an error. Here is how I proceed:

I pre-register the card with:

```
echo '{  
  "UserId": "67844304", 
  "Currency": "EUR",  
  "CardType": "CB_VISA_MASTERCARD"
}' | http -a filoo:myApiKey POST https://api.sandbox.mangopay.com/v2.01/filoo/cardregistrations
```

It works and I can ask to add a new card with the informations I get:

```
 echo '{
        "PreregistrationData": "dtxlzFRSvUcdNkJimn-i_L64-_r7M5oECwslrv8Q04NgHVv1mxYX6qXicHf0SGAMS4wCy-yiraxeE65tmxOe8A",
        "AccessKey": "1X0m87dmM2LiwFgxPLBJ",
        "cardNumber": "4706750000000009",
        "cardExpirationDate": "1221",
        "cardCvx": "123"
    }' | http -a filoo:myApiKey POST https://homologation-webpayment.payline.com/webpayment/getToken
```

But I get this very comprehensive error code inside the body of the response (with a 200 HTTP status code): `errorCode=09101`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue and I resolved this problem by passing HTTP params as querystring.

Try to pass this way https://flaviocopes.com/axios-urlencoded/